# Using privateFor in truffle test

Tags: truffle, quorum, truffle-test

Using truffle , I am able to deploy private smart contracts using privateFor clause. However, I am not able to use in truffle test. I get the following error. Is there a way we can  use privateFor ?

Transaction: 0x0e390b0d04d6285bd098f76ebfa961b8be875ce2a744511e13eb312414f835a8 exited with an error (status 0).
 Please check that the transaction:
 - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.
 - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.

Sample Test

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
const DEF_Test = artifacts.require("DEF_Test");
const Testing_V1 = artifacts.require("Testing_V1");
const Event_V1 = artifacts.require("Event_V1");

// Test cases 
contract("Testing_V1 Testing", async accounts => {

    let Testing_V1Instance;
    let Event_V1Instance;

    it("1. Setting up Contract instances", async () => {
        Testing_V1Instance = await Testing_V1.new();
        Event_V1Instance = await Event_V1.new();
    })

    it("set", async () => {
        let result = await Testing_V1Instance.set("ID","Name",["ph1","ph2"],Event_V1Instance.address,
            {from:"0x12eac5277d794e1a0d65c95f9fe2b721a86d096f",
            privateFor:["l/VcNHe+p+KX79dbGpAydcMiKGkaBbwSkdInlP6PHD0=",
                        "K76aVoHUc5RkNpkreFd64DYyzxG1UO5aCd05h1u97EA="]});
            console.log(result)
        });

    it("get", async () => {
        let result = await Testing_V1Instance.get("ID");
        console.log(result)
    })

})
```

Sample code

```
pragma solidity 0.5.13;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "../definitions/DEF_Test.sol";
import "./Event_V1.sol";
import "../interface/ITesting_V1.sol";

contract Testing_V1 is ITesting_V1 {

mapping (string => DEF_Test.Employee) private mapEmp;

function set(string memory empID, string memory empName,string[] memory phone,address eventAddr) public{
    mapEmp[empID].empID = empID;
    mapEmp[empID].empName = empName;
    mapEmp[empID].phone = phone;
    Event_V1(eventAddr).emitEmpEvent(mapEmp[empID]);
}

function get(string memory empID) public view returns (DEF_Test.Employee memory) {
    return mapEmp[empID];
}

}

pragma solidity 0.5.13;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
import "../definitions/DEF_Test.sol";

contract Event_V1 {

    event EMP_EVENT(string empID,string empName,string[] phone);

    function emitEmpEvent(DEF_Test.Employee memory emp)  public  {
        emit EMP_EVENT(emp.empID,emp.empName,emp.phone);
    }


}

pragma solidity 0.5.13;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

library DEF_Test {

struct Employee {
    string empID;
    string empName;
    string[] phone;
}


}

pragma solidity 0.5.13;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "../definitions/DEF_Test.sol";

interface ITesting_V1 {

function set(string calldata empID, string calldata empName,string[] calldata phone,address eventAddr) external;
function get(string calldata empID) external view returns (DEF_Test.Employee memory);

}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant contract code and the relevant test code.